# apache poi finding number of rows in a sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have been using these methods to count the number of rows in a sheet

```
getLastRowNum()
```

and

```
getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
```

They are working fine on two sheets of my workbook. But the third sheet containing 5 rows is returning 1 extra with both of the functions.

```
Sheet NumberofRows getLastRowNum() getPhysicalNumberOfRows()
1     9            9               10
2     56           56              57
3     5            4               5
```

What exactly is the difference in the working of the two functions and what can I do so I get reliable correct results?

Answer (score 12):

**getLastRowNum()**

- **the number of the last row** contained in this sheet, **start from zero**

> i.e Like an array it starts from 0 to n-1 if n is the number of rows.

**getPhysicalNumberOfRows()**

- the number of physically defined rows in this sheet. Not include the empty row

So for the number of rows 10, **getLastRowNum()** will be **9**, as it start from **0**. 
This is one of the reason that `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` should be used instead of `getLastRowNum()` because if the number of rows is 1 in the sheet, `getLastRowNum()` would return `0` which cannot differentiate if there is 0 row or the only row is at position `0` while `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` would return 1.

Comment: But like I mentioned, for the number of rows 9, getPhysicalNumberOfRows is giving me 10. And not in all cases is it adding 1 to the number.

Comment: Can you check the start of the sheet, the first row; any blank row any unused row, etc or if possible share the xls.

Comment: I can't share the workbook, but it is actually xlsx. Would that change things? Also, by the documentation from apache poi, and as suggested by you, for numOfRows = 9, getPhysicalNumberOfRows() should return 9. But it is giving me 10. On a sheet with 5 rows, however, it is giving me 5.

Comment: Check for hidden rows in between or if there is a header or you might have entered something in the last column. Clear everything and try. Might help.

Comment: Couldn't find anything. I even made a new workbook. Same results!

Comment: Okk. Will try to execute it in my machine and check.

Comment: Could you share your apache-poi version and also the xls.

Comment: Can't share the xls. but poi version i am using is 3.10

Comment: Not the actual but the new workbook that has the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found the built-in methods to be unreliable (inconsistently off by +/-1) so I rolled my own:

```
// returns index of next blank line
public static int getNextRow(Sheet sheet) {
    int rowIndex = 0;
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    Cell c = null;
    try {
        c = row.getCell(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return rowIndex;
    }
    while (!emptyCell(c)) {
        rowIndex++;
        row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (row != null) {
                c = row.getCell(0);
        } else {
                break;
        }
    }
    return rowIndex;
}
```